# Async function call issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows Phone application. While invoking the below function, after executing this line:
`HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(connection1).ConfigureAwait(false);`
 it skips the rest of the code and control goes to the parent function and execute the rest of the code there and come back to this function again. How to fix this problem?

```
public async void vehicleValidation()    
{
    //isValidVehicle = true;
    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    //string connection = "http://mymlcp.co.in/mlcpapp/get_slot.php?vehiclenumber=KL07BQ973";
    string connection1 = string.Format("http://mymlcp.co.in/mlcpapp/?tag=GetIsValidUser&employeeId={0}&name={1}",txtVeh.Text,"abc");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(connection1).ConfigureAwait(false);
    //var response = await client.GetAsync(connection1);
   // HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(connection1).Result;
    var cont = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var floorObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(cont);
    //var resp = await (new MLCPClient()).GetIsValidUser(txtVeh.Text, "xyz");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(floorObj["error"].ToString()) || floorObj["error"].ToString().Equals("true"))
    {
        isValidVehicle = false;
    }
    else
    {

        isValidVehicle = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that control being returned to the caller when you need to await something is *exactly* what you should expect with an async method. That's half the point.

Comment: I don't think you should use `ConfigureAwait(false)`  as it raises `synchronization` issues.

Comment: @jonSkeet Can you explain?

Comment: Not in comments, no - you really need to spend some time reading up on what async/await does.

Answer (score 1):

You should never have `async void` unless you are writing a event handler, you need to make your function return a `Task` and then `await` the function in your parent function.

Read "[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)" for a introduction on the best practices like never doing `async void` and making your code "async all the way"

Comment: Also PascalCase should be used when naming methods.